# Can't create tag bundle that contains [seo]

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, tag-filters

So I'm trying to create a StackExchange tag bundle for SEO.

I've added the tag [seo-friendly]  [successfully](https://stackexchange.com/tagsets/8385/seo), but when I try to add the tag [seo], the spinner appears and spins forever. It never displays the site selection tools or the Add button.

Seems to be a bug, right?

Comment: What if you hit Enter?

Comment: Something weird is going on with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed now. It was trying to show "Meta Atheism" (which apparently had an [seo] tag), but it was failing since [atheism.stackexchange.com](http://atheism.stackexchange.com) no longer exists.

Comment: Confirmed fixed. Thanks Emmett!